# Using dom to scrape the source code coming from file_get_content

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping

I am trying to get review, rate and date from this page:

> http://www.yelp.com/biz/franchino-san-francisco?start=80

By taking the some code from page I could get the result here:

https://eval.in/143036

But when I apply it for entire page source using `file_get_contents` it gives set of warning like:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 700 in F:\wamp\www\htdocs\thenwat\yelp.php.

I used `escapeshellarg` and `nl2br` to remove this issue but no help.

Please see : https://eval.in/143074

Below code works fine for smaller source snipper : https://eval.in/143036

```
$classname = 'rating-qualifier';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");

if ($results->length > 0) {
    echo $review = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
}   
$classname = 'review_comment ieSucks';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");    
if ($results->length > 0) {
    echo $review = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
}    
$meta = $dom->documentElement->getElementsByTagName("meta");
echo $meta->item(0)->getAttribute('content');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOMDocument is great for well formed documents but not all HTML pages are well formed.  Use  **Simple HTML DOM** http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/ instead.  I have created a **working solution** that extracts the data you requested.

#### yelp.php

```
<?php

  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

   /************************************************
   *                                               *
   *    2014.04.28                                 *
   *    Developed by Ben McFarlin at Qeala Labs    *
   *    www.qeala.com                              *
   *                                               *
   ************************************************/

    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

  function yelp($url){
    print("$url\n");

    $root = new stdClass();
    $items = array();
    $html = file_get_html($url);

    if($html){

      $containers = $html->find('div.review-list div.review div.review-wrapper');
      foreach($containers as $container){
        $comments = $container->find('div.review-content p.review_comment');
        $item = new stdClass();
        foreach($comments as $comment){
          $comment_html = $comment->innertext();
          $item->comment = $comment_html;
        }
        $metas = $container->find('div.review-content meta');
        foreach($metas as $meta){
          $itemprop = $meta->itemprop;
          $content = $meta->content;
          if($itemprop == 'ratingValue') $key = 'rating';
          else $key = 'date';
          $item->$key = $content;
        }
        $items[] = $item;
      }
    }

    $root->items = $items;

    if($html){
      $html->clear();
      unset($html);
    }

    return $root;
  }

  $url = 'http://www.yelp.com/biz/franchino-san-francisco?start=80';
  $root = yelp($url);
  var_dump($root);


?>
```

#### Update

I have FireFox with the Firebug extension installed. While viewing the web page, I right click on the data I want to capture and choose ***Inspect Element with FireBug.***  The debug window opens with the HTML element already selected. I right click on that element and choose ***Copy CSS Path.***  That will give the full CSS selector for the element.  Normally it's way too specific and can be reduced to just a few elements.  I then review the HTML structure (already open in the debug window) to determine what I can eliminate.  At that point it's just a matter of knowing CSS selectors. Hope that helps. It may take some practice but you will find that technique invaluable for any type of HTML/CSS work.

[Firefox Web Browser](http://firefox.com)

[Firebug Web Development Tool](http://getfirebug.com/)

[Learn CSS at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)

Comment: can you please tell me how you have selected `class name` here? what is the logic for it?